# Reading Multidimensional PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I've ceated a PHP Array which output looks like the following:

```php
Array (
    [1429645] => Array ( 
        [name]          => John Smith
        [days_employed] => 15
        [wage]          => 25000
    )
    [1183240] => Array ( 
        [name]          => Sarah Smith
        [days_employed] => 65
        [wage]          => 30000
    )
)
```

I am going to be looping through the data to create a table, however I'm trying to understand what I have and print some data of like so;

```php
<?PHP echo print_r($employeeData[0][wage]); ?>
```

The above intent was; `first employee => wage => value`

After several attempts, several dozen pages being looked at, trying with and without speech emphasis, nothing appears to have given any output apart from at one point I saw `1` dispite that not being a value I could relate to.

Have I created a standard PHP array and how can I read values correctly?

Comment: You can't use `[0]` as no element exists with 0 as a key.  You could try `echo reset($arr)['wage'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim!

You don't have zero index in your array, this must work:

`<?php echo $employeeData[1429645]['wage']; ?>`

You can null indeces of your array by `$employeeData = array_values($employeeData);` and then you could use your current code.

But more correct would be so:

```
foreach ($employeeData as $data) {
        echo $data['wage'];
}
```

Comment: So without knowing the ID, I cannot use the position which is what I was trying to do?

Comment: How could I also print the current ID within this foreach loop please?

Comment: For that you should loop so: ```foreach ($employeeData as $key => $data)```.
Just if you don't need thet index you can omit ```$key```

Answer (score 1):

Your employee number, from the looks at it, is your key.

```
$employees[1429645] = ['name'          => 'John Smith' ,
                       'days_employed' => 15 ,
                       'wage'          => 25000];

foreach ($employees as $details) {

    echo $details['name'] . ' gets paid ' . 
         $details['wage'] . ' and has been employed for ' . 
         $details['days_employed'] . ' days';

}
```